# JSON writeValueAsString returns 1 if attribut has the same result attributes

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jpa, objectmapper

i am a bit confused. I get a result from my database by native-select statement

```
TypedQuery<User> query = entityManager.createQuery(
            "SELECT i FROM User i", User.class);
    result = query.getFirstResult;
```

with user_created and user_updated as attributes by User. The result looks pretty well (whole user_created and user_updated attributes), but if I use

```
String entity = objectMapper.writerWithView(v).writeValueAsString(result);
```

the entity looks like:

```
"user_created": {
    "@id": 1,
    "id": 11737,
    "fullname": "Max Mustermann",
    "email": "max.mustermann@gmx.de",
    "username": "maxi"
},
"user_updated": 1,
```

it should look like:

```
  "user_created": {
        "@id": 1,
        "id": 11737,
        "fullname": "Max Mustermann",
        "email": "max.mustermann@gmx.de",
        "username": "maxi"
    },
  "user_updated": {
        "@id": 1,
        "id": 11737,
        "fullname": "Max Mustermann",
        "email": "max.mustermann@gmx.de",
        "username": "maxi"
    },
```

If I have two different user for user_updated and user_created on same result, the result looks like it should:

```
 "user_created": {
        "@id": 1,
        "id": 11737,
        "fullname": "Max Mustermann",
        "email": "max.mustermann@gmx.de",
        "username": "maxi"
    },
  "user_updated": {
        "@id": 1,
        "id": 4172,
        "fullname": "Simone Musterfrau",
        "email": "simone.musterfrau@gmx.de",
        "username": "simi"
    },
```

Maybe there is a Problem with a same result? Like I said, the result after SELECT Query looks how it should.

I found the central problem. On my entity I use

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@id", scope = User.class)
```

But I need this on my entity. Maybe someone can tell me, if there is any object for the objectmapper or if I can add some attributes to my entity.

Comment: Can you please specify how do you obtain user_updated object ?

Comment: Like i mentioned, thats a result from database

Comment: Can you please mention the method (merge, ...) that you have used from hibernate and the position of the user_updated in this call (arg, return value) ?

Comment: Guess you dont unterstand my problem. Just have a resultset as entity from a database which I want to parse to a JSON with objectmapper. And the method writeValueAsString parses the user_updated to 1 instead of full user like my user_created, of the user_created and user_updated has the same values.

Comment: really it is very strange :( but I encourage you to put more code on your question to help other people understand your problem and hopefully give you an answer because, like this, it's very hard to understand what's going on

Comment: Are you using JsonIdentityInfo?

Comment: Yes I use JsonIdentifyInfo